# Select distinct ,count and groupBy in Sql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am joining the tables to return data but I want that data to be grouped by specific location and also count/sum the values that are related to that location 
at the moment I can only retrieve the data but it does not sum/count the values of that location Here is my query

```
    select brand_locations.locationName,campaign_stats.clicks,
    campaign_stats.impressions,
    campaign_stats.day,brand_locations.city,

    click_actions.walkTo,click_actions.showMap,
    click_actions.call,click_actions.coupon,driveTo,campaigns_details.state 
    from campaign_stats
             inner join campaigns_details on campaign_stats.campaignId = campaigns_details.campaignId               
             inner join click_actions on click_actions.campaignId=campaign_stats.campaignId
             inner join brand_locations on brand_locations.brandId = campaigns_details.brandId
             where brand_locations.city = 'cape town'
```

The output is

```
bellville       58
water front     12
bellville        4
bellville        1
century city     2
century city     4
```

My goal is to have

```
bellville       63
water front     12
century city     6
```

Thanks

Comment: Good point: you give us the output you get and what you expect. But without an idea on input data, can be pretty hard to figure it out...

Comment: Have you tried `select sum(campaign_stats.click)` `group_by (brand_locations.locationName)`

Comment: SELECT locationName,SUM(clicks) FROM (your query here) x GROUP BY locationName; ?

Comment: all the data is stored in different tables the only thing i was able to retrieve was the data based on the links of ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query.  I have added a group by location name to the query and also used function sum to calcualate the total number of clicks.

```
select brand_locations.locationName,SUM(campaign_stats.clicks) as campaign_stats_cnt,
    sum(campaign_stats.impressions) as impressions_cnt,
    campaign_stats.day,brand_locations.city,

    click_actions.walkTo,click_actions.showMap,
    click_actions.call,click_actions.coupon,driveTo,campaigns_details.state 
    from campaign_stats
             inner join campaigns_details on campaign_stats.campaignId = campaigns_details.campaignId               
             inner join click_actions on click_actions.campaignId=campaign_stats.campaignId
             inner join brand_locations on brand_locations.brandId = campaigns_details.brandId
             where brand_locations.city = 'cape town' group by brand_locations.locationName
```

Comment: thanks this is working fine the only problem is SUM(campaign_stats.clicks): "34"
SUM(campaign_stats.impressions): "179"

Comment: i can'taccess it in javascript like value.SUM(campaign_stats.impressions) to  to output 179 It is giving me the error

Comment: I have edited my answer.  I have added alias for the retrieved sum column. check it out

Answer (score 1):

MySQL SUM() function retrieves the sum value of an expression which has undergone a grouping operation by GROUP BY clause. Have you tried this option?

```
select brand_locations.locationName,SUM(campaign_stats.clicks),
campaign_stats.impressions,
campaign_stats.day,brand_locations.city,

click_actions.walkTo,click_actions.showMap,
click_actions.call,click_actions.coupon,driveTo,campaigns_details.state 
from campaign_stats
         inner join campaigns_details on campaign_stats.campaignId = campaigns_details.campaignId               
         inner join click_actions on click_actions.campaignId=campaign_stats.campaignId
         inner join brand_locations on brand_locations.brandId = campaigns_details.brandId
         where brand_locations.city = 'cape town' group by brand_locations.locationName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` to get the results you want from the result you are getting

```
SELECT title, SUM(count) 
FROM (resultQuery) 
GROUP BY title
```

**NOTE:** Replace title with the `name` of your first column, `count` with the name of your second column and `resultQuery` with they query you have above

And yes, this is the hacky sub-query way of doing it....